# Sharing Data Between User Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, ado.net, designer

How do I share data between user-controls in .Net, using ADO.net datasets, without ditching the designer?  A simple example:

I have two separate user-controls; **Control1**, which contains a textbox, and **Control2**, which contains a label.  Both the textbox and the label are bound (using the designer) to the same property in the same dataset.  If I drag both **Control1** and **Control2** into the same form, I would expect that changing the textbox would change the label.  However, it doesn't, since **Control1** and **Control2** have separate DataSets and BindingSources.  I want to keep the textbox and label synchronized without having to ditch the designer and code the entire form by hand.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a relative source in your binding expression.

Comment: I don't understand - please explain